# Is the community avatar a mod?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that the community avatar has a diamond next to itself. Does this mean that it can act like a mod? If so, what are its actual mod duties?

Comment: This kind of general questions is usually already answered on [meta.se].

Answer (score 2):

This question is being answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user).

It actually is a bot that has mod access in order to fulfil certain tasks of tidying up and pushing to the top etc.

The full range of its tasks is laid out in the Meta.SE post linked above.

Comment: I've read the post, and it seems to me that it does not just 'randomly poke' posts; it seems to me that there is more to this than at first meets the eye.